# Ubuntu Cloud Images - Desktop versions

Tags: gui, desktop-environments, disk-image, qcow2

I was wondering why on official [Ubuntu cloud image repository](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com) there are only server versions and not standard desktop images (with GUI).

Which is the simplest way to create it?

Thanks!

Comment: Because the Ubuntu Cloud site is server centric and it's meant to be strictly for server builds.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if Canonical provides 'Descktop centric' image repository site? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because

> Ubuntu Cloud Images [...] to run on public clouds that provide Ubuntu Certified Images, Openstack, LXD, and more.

What does "[Public Cloud](http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/public-cloud)" mean?

[From Webopedia](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/public_cloud.html)

> A form of cloud computing in which a company relies on a third-party cloud service provider for services such as servers, data storage and applications, which are delivered to the company through the Internet. A public cloud can free companies from the potentially expensive costs of having to purchase, manage and maintain on-premises hardware and software infrastructure.

And you will obviously need a guest to access this server, so from [the FAQs on Ubuntu Cloud Guest](http://insights.ubuntu.com/wp-content/uploads/226b/Ubuntu-Cloud-Guest.pdf)

> **1 What is Ubuntu Cloud Guest?**
>   Ubuntu Cloud Guest is a version of Ubuntu Server LTS
>   that is optimised for the cloud, enabling instances of
>   Ubuntu to run as guest operating systems on top of cloud
>   infrastructure. [...]

A typical example that I am most familiar with is AWS from Amazon, where you can run a Ubuntu server remotely (and install a GUI on it if you really want it) for free - if you comply with some limitations.